# Working out a fixed rate and grand total in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in where a user enters information and then a calculation is performed.

For some reason, the fixed rate and my grand total isn't being outputted in the html.

Here is my script.

```
function updateCost()
{
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var delivery = parseInt($('#delivery').val());
    var fixedrate =  parseInt($('#total').val() / 100 * 12.4);

    var total = parseInt(amount) + parseInt(delivery);
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#amountdiv").html(amount);
    $("#deliverydiv").html(delivery);

    var grandtotal = parseInt(fixed) + parseInt(total);
    $("#grandtotal").html(grandtotal);
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#fixedrate").html(fixedrate);   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amount').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#delivery').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#grandtotal').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
});
```

The HTML is this..

```
Payment:
<div name="amount" id="amountdiv"></div>
Freight:   
<div name="delivery" id="deliverydiv"></div> 
Total Payment:
<div name="total" id="total"></div>
Due Date:    
<div name="date" id="date"></div>    
Fixed:    
<div name="fixed" id="fixedrate"></div>    
Grand Total:
<div name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal"></div>
```

Thanks Jonah

Comment: How is the user inputting the values? The elements are all `div`s, shouldn't they be `input`s?

Comment: Is this all of your HTML, or are the form inputs elsewhere? If this is all your HTML, this is easy to fix - just want to make sure we have all the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant

```
 var grandtotal = parseInt(fixedrate) + parseInt(total);
```

But also the line

```
var fixedrate =  parseInt($('#total').val() / 100 * 12.4);
```

the `$('#total').val()` get the empty content of the div and result in 0 from the parseInt

Here is a sample of what the function could look like:

```
function updateCost()
{
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var delivery = parseInt($('#delivery').val());


    var total = parseInt(amount) + parseInt(delivery);
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#amountdiv").html(amount);
    $("#deliverydiv").html(delivery);

    var fixedrate =  parseInt(total / 100 * 12.4);

    var grandtotal = parseInt(fixedrate) + parseInt(total);
    $("#grandtotal").html(grandtotal);
    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#fixedrate").html(fixedrate);  

}
```

Comment: Hi, but the #total, is worked out by the user inputting the 'amount' and 'delivery'?  So in theory the div shouldn't be 0.

Comment: Ok then you need to update the div before with the content from the input and make sure there inst not confusion with the id total

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
var grandtotal = parseInt(fixed) + parseInt(total);
```

should probably be

```
var grandtotal = parseInt(fixedrate) + parseInt(total);
```

Comment: Good spot, although Fixed Rate is coming out as 0.

Comment: Is it possible that "total" is assigned to both an input field and a div? .val() only works for input fields AFAIK, it simply returns undefined when used on other elements.

Comment: There are only two input fields. One called 'amount', the other called 'delivery'.  Everything should be worked out from these two fields.